# Find out number of words in a string with a lot of special character

Tags: java, regex

I need to find out the number of words in a string. However, this string is not the normal type of string. It has a lot of special character like < , /em, /p and many more. So most of the method used in StackOverflow does not work. As a result, I need to define a regular expression by myself.

What I intend to do is to define what is a word using a regular expression and count the number of time a word appears.
This is how I define a word.
It must start with a letter and end with one of this : or , or ! or ? or ' or - or ) or . or "

This is how I define my regular expression

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z](:|,|!|?|'|-|)|.|")$");
matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) 
wordCount++;
```

However, there is an error with the first line

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z](:|,|!|?|'|-|)|.|")$");
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Escape the double-quote. `"^[a-zA-Z](:|,|!|?|'|-|)|.|\")$"`

Comment: Show us sample input and output :)

Comment: I am confused, in your code you show `"^[a-zA-Z](:|,|!|?|'|-|)|.|")$"` but then you mention `"^a-zA-Z|.|")$"` - which one are you trying to use?

Comment: The string literal is corrupt since the double quote should be escaped inside it. Also, I believe the dot is also a literal dot here, same for `)`.

Comment: The primary problem you have is expecting to find the *exact* solution to all your problems, *verbatem*, on SO.

Comment: Try `pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+[:,!?').\"-]");`

Comment: What about “words” at the end of the String that don’t have any character after them?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
String line = "so.this:is,what)you!wanted?";
int wordCount = 0;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]++[:'-,\\.!\\?\")]{1})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    wordCount++;
}
System.out.println(wordCount); // Prints 6
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact you also want to remove tags, like `<em>` (HTML emphasized), which otherwise would count as words. If you then consider full tags with attributes:
`<span font="Consolas">` then it is easier to remove tags:

```
public int static wordCount(String s) {
    s.replaceAll("<[A-Za-z/][^>]*>", " ") // Tags as space
        .replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{M}\\d]+", " ") // Non-letters, -accents, -digits as blank
        .trim() // Not before or after (empty words)
        .split(" ").length;
}
```

It is quite inefficient, replaceAll and trim. At least precompiling and using Pattern would be nicer. But probably not worth it.